# Xamarin Forms - Show Maps Info windows like Uber App

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Please assist

I have been struggling in showing a trip on my carpooling app much like the one on an Uber. That is with two info windows for both start and end locations open with their respective addresses.

I have managed to render a custom info window the way I want to but can not make all the info windows open. How can I do one of the following:

Override the current logic that prevents google Maps to open more than one info window at a time.
Draw over the map to display a custom view right next to the Map pin.

I am using 'Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps'

- Visual goal(Only top part of screen)

[image]

- Xamarin.Android Custom Render Class

  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
  namespace CoTripApp.Droid.CustomRennders
  {
  public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
  {

  ```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            //nativemap.infowindowclick -= oninfowindowclick;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsmap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
        }

    }

    protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap nativeMap, Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Map map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(nativeMap, map);
        NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
    }
    protected override void OnMarkerCreated(Pin pin, Marker marker)
    {
        marker.Position = new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude);
        marker.Title = pin.Label;
        marker.Snippet = pin.Address;

        if (pin.Type.Equals(PinType.Generic))
        {
            marker.SetIcon(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.circle));
        }
        else
        {
            marker.SetIcon(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.circle_closed));
        }

        marker.ShowInfoWindow();
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        Android.Views.View view;

        var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
        if (inflater != null)
        {
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomMapInfoWindow, null);

            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.waypointNo).Text = marker.Title;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.address).Text = marker.Snippet;

            return view;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
        return null;
    }
  ```

  }

  }

Comment: You need to include a reproducible example of what you have tried and demonstrate in what way it is not working, as well as clearly identify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: please post the relevant code.  There is no way we can help you if you don't show us what you are actually doing.

Comment: Hi, guys appreciate the help sorry I only now added the code.
I scrapped a lot of the code I had while I was trying to achieve my goal because the map visual was not crucial at the time so I just went with what I could produce. But now I need to get the map looking in a certain way. This is the code I have in my project at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried to set the label of pin? It would show the Map Info  window. Please check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins#display-a-pin